# Ng-View is commented out on page load

Tags: angularjs

For some reason, when I load my page with an ng-view on it, said ng-view is commented out when I inspect it in my console, and I have no idea why.

Reading other threads with a similar problem has proven fruitless. See code snippets below. Currently just console logging routeParams as I am a newbie to AngularJS and I want to make sure I get all the values I need and know what to work with. This is in a Rails project, for reference:

**Show Page**

```
    <div class ="row" ng-view>
</div>
```

**App.js**

```
    'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module("summoners-universe", ['ngRoute'])


    myApp.config(['$routeProvider', "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
      $routeProvider.when("games/:id", {
        templateUrl: "timer.html",
        controller: 'CountdownController'
      })
      $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false }); 
    }])
```

**controllers.js**

```
'use strict';
myApp.controller('CountdownController', ["$scope", "$http", "$routeParams", function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
  console.log($routeParams)
}])
```

Comment: Are you actually on the `games/:id` page? You might want to put an `otherwise` on your route config to confirm that it is at least set up correctly.

Comment: it is normal for the `ng-view` element to be commented out; it is only a placeholder that tells angular where the template from the `templateUrl` (`timer.html`, in your case) should be injected.  The code inside the template file **completely** replaces the commented out `ng-view` element.  If you are not providing a template file, or you are on a route that doesn't exist or doesn't have a `templateUrl`, the area will be empty.

Comment: @MatthewGreen I put the otherwise statement in as you recommended, redirecting to my route. Now, when I go to the games/:id page, the route changes from the current game to the route.

For example, with the otherwise statement in, when I click on a specific game show page, the url will flash for a brief second as "localhost:3000/games/20" (if it's 20), to "localhost:3000"

Answer (score 0):

Ah, simple syntax error. I didn't have a leading backslash for that games/:id route! It should look like /games/:id.